# SwipeRefreshLayout - Scrolling slowly causes glitches to the ListView

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using the new component from support library rev 19.1 - SwipeRefreshLayout.

It seems to work nicely, excepts one thing:
When I scroll the ListView slowly (In order to trigger the pull-to-refresh), the scrolling has glitches (the list jumps up and down).
This doesn't happen when I scroll fast or scroll down (regular scroll, not the pull-to-refresh section).

Here's how I connect the SwipeRefreshLayout in xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Is there a fix for this issue?

Thanks in adavnce!

Comment: seems like a bug to me. It also occurs on a scrollview.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing this as well with GridViews (and I assume potentially any child of the SwipeRefreshLayout). Unsure of the cause at the moment. Post any findings you come across :)